# Using correctly the product rule?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have been told to use the product rule whenever I have two functions of same variable say, $x$ and I differentiate with respect to $x$ i.e.

$f(x)g(x) = f(x)g'(x) + g(x)f'(x)$

Now, what if I had two dependent variables in the equation say, $p$ and $y$?

Is it perfectly fine to say:

$f(p)g(y) = f(p)g'(y) + g(p)f'(y)$

with respect to $x$ ?

For example in an equation like:

$y = x^2p + x$

Comment: By "dependent," do you mean that $p$ and $y$ are two functions of $x$? In this case, the product rule would apply, **BUT** you would need to apply the chain rule as well.

Comment: They are two functions. say, $y=f(x,p)$ from topic "Equations solvable for 'y'" under differential equations.

Comment: The formula is $(f(x)g(x))' = f(x)g'(x) + g(x)f'(x)$ - you left out the first '.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that $p$ and $y$ are functions of $x$, then the rule works (although you must also apply the chain rule)

If you mean that $p$ and $y$ are both just variables independent of $x$, then $\frac{d}{dx} f(p)g(y) = 0$.

If you are calculating $\frac{d}{dx} f(x,p)$ as you would get if you differentiated your equation you have something entirely different, and this would usually be written as a partial derivative if $p$ is independent

There are even more possibilities based on how vague your question is. I will update as you do.